# How to check Swift nested enums for equality of the outer enum only?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to use nested enums to describe my model, in a way that makes illegal states impossible and provides categorisation at the top level. Right now, my (simplified) code is:

```
enum SportsEvent {

    enum RunningEvent {
        case sprint
        case marathon
    }

    enum ThrowingEvent {
        case hammer
        case javelin
        case discus
    }

    case running(event: RunningEvent)
    case throwing(event: ThrowingEvent)

    func isSameCategory(as other: SportsEvent) -> Bool {

        return false
    }
}

let sprint = SportsEvent.running(event: .sprint)
let javelin = SportsEvent.throwing(event: .javelin)
let hammer = SportsEvent.throwing(event: .hammer)

sprint.isSameCategory(as: javelin)      // False
hammer.isSameCategory(as: javelin)      // True
```

It feels like it should be trivial with an `if case ...` and a wildcard, but I'm not seeing how to achieve that. I'm hoping a giant switch statement isn't necessary, as my actual model is more complex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a switch-statement, with a “compound case” listing all
possible “same value combinations” of the outer enumeration,
plus a default case:

```
func isSameCategory(as other: SportsEvent) -> Bool {
    switch (self, other) {
    case (.running, .running),
         (.throwing, .throwing):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

Or (attribution goes to @Hamish):

```
func isSameCategory(as other: SportsEvent) -> Bool {
    switch (self, other) {
    case (.running, .running),
         (.throwing, .throwing):
        return true
    case (.running, _),
         (.throwing, _):
        return false
    }
}
```

which has the advantage that the compiler checks that all cases are covered. For an enumeration with `n` cases that makes `2 * n` 
cases in the switch statement (which is better than `n * n` if you checked all possible combinations).

Comment: Looks good, and not too much of a maintenance problem as the set of outer values is likely to be quite/very stable.

Comment: Note that if you want the compiler to ensure you've covered all the cases, you can replace the `default` with something like `case (.running, _), (.throwing, _): return false`. It's more duplication, but you get the added guarantee that all cases are covered. Hopefully a future version of Swift will make it much easier to work with enums with associated values though – the current situation isn't ideal.

Comment: @Hamish: That is what I was still trying to figure out – thanks!

Comment:  @Hamish, I like the removal of `default:`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, you might be able to convert `SportEvent` to a protocol:

```
enum RunningEvent {
    case sprint
    case marathon
}

enum ThrowingEvent {
    case hammer
    case javelin
    case discus
}

enum SportEventCategory {
    case running
    case throwing
}

protocol SportEvent {
    var category: SportEventCategory { get }
}

extension RunningEvent: SportEvent {
    var category: SportEventCategory {
        return .running
    }
}

extension ThrowingEvent: SportEvent {
    var category: SportEventCategory {
        return .throwing
    }
}

let sportEvent1: SportEvent = RunningEvent.sprint
let sportEvent2: SportEvent = ThrowingEvent.hammer
print(sportEvent1.category == sportEvent2.category)
```

or even as one flat enum:

```
enum SportEvent {
    enum Category {
        case running
        case throwing
    }

    case sprint
    case marathon
    case hammer
    case javelin
    case discus

    var category: Category {
        switch self {
        case .sprint, .marathon, .hammer:
            return .running
        case .javelin, .discus:
            return .throwing
        }
    }
}

let sportEvent1: SportEvent = .sprint
let sportEvent2: SportEvent = .marathon
print(sportEvent1.category == sportEvent2.category)
```

Comment: An interesting alternative, thanks. I need to give it (in the real use case) more thought.

Comment: @Chris There are many possibilities. You could also have only one enum for both running and throwing events and just add a `var category` for all of them. There are many ways to do the same and it's hard to find the best one.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Eventually I will be using the outer category for grouping (something like `[(category: SportEventCategory, events: [Event])]`, for use by a UITableViewDataSource) so I need to choose an approach that suits that. The initial pure enum version is not a very good fit. I will try applying your flattened enum approach.